# How can we say that one reaction is faster than another if two conflicting factors are at play in both of them

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

While learning about the preparation of alkyl halides from alcohols by reacting them with hydrohalic acids, it was mentioned that the order of reactivity of different alcohols is Tertiary > Secondary > Primary and also that since the reaction takes place via nucleophilic substitution, the reactivity order also varies as $HI > HBr > HCl$ , as $I^-$ is a stronger nucleophile than $Br^-$ and so on. My question is that, if we consider two reactions, one of a secondary alcohol with HI and another of a tertiary alcohol reacting with HCl, then which of the two will be faster and why?

I tried to come with an answer and I think it may be that the Rate Determining Step is the one where the carbocation is formed and thus the tertiary alcohol will undergo the reaction faster in all cases. Pls let me know if this is right or wrong.

Comment: General trends like the ones you mention are useful. But they should not be used to generally quantify an effect. Therefore, mixing two trends the way you suggest makes no sense.